# Package not found in NPM through registry

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am totally new to devops, and I have a problem I don't know why it may be occurring.

We have our own registry with only two upstream sources:

```
source: npmjs
location: https://npmjs.org/
```

```
source: nuget.org
location: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Until now, I have had no problem installing packages. Then I tried to install `sequelize-cli-typescript` and the following error appeared:

```
400 Bad Request - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/~azure-project~/npm/registry/sequelize-cli-typescript/-/sequelize-cli-typescript-3.2.0-c.tgz
```

I ran `npm set registry https://npmjs.org/' and tried to install the package again. It was installed successfully.

I understand that our registry should be using npmjs as a source, so every package available in npmjs should be available in our registry. What may be happening?

I am sorry if there is any setting I should have included. Again, I am new to devops. But let me know and I will add it.

Thank you!

---

EDIT

I am able to install random npm packages without problem. It seems to be only a problem with `sequelize-cli-typescript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled `sequelize-cli` and then I was able to install `sequelize-cli-typescript` perfectly.